# I have some problems with ManytoMany between two entities in version 3.1.8. Successfully added data but unable to retrieve previously existing data

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

Here is my dependency

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

> My application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;databaseName=JWT_DEMO_ROLES;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa2008
#allow table name we like
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I am setting up Spring Security for using JWT, so I will implement UserDetails.

> My User Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@Table(name = "nguoidung")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "user_sequence",
            sequenceName = "user_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1 //increment by 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "user_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    //...skip other attributes

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idrole")})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles.stream().map(
                        role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    //...skip override method
}
```

> My Role Entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="roles")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "role_sequence",
            sequenceName = "role_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1 //increment by 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "role_sequence"
    )
    private Integer idrole;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

To simplify, I create a user and a role. Then, I add the role to the user so that I can later verify their permissions and getUserById to check their roles

> My AuthenticationController

```
@PostMapping("/signup-simple")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> signUpSimple(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        if (user != null) {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        }
        assert user != null;
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseObject("ok", "create User successfully", userRepository.save(user)));
    }
@PostMapping("/create-role")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> createRole(@ModelAttribute Role role) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseObject("ok", "Crete Role successfully", roleRepository.save(role)));
    }
@PutMapping("/addRole/{idRole}/{idUser}")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> addRoleToStudent(@PathVariable Integer idRole, @PathVariable Long idUser) {
        Role role = roleRepository.findById(idRole).orElse(null);
        User user = userRepository.findById(idUser).orElse(null);
        assert user != null;
        user.getRoles().add(role);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseObject("ok", "add role successfully", userRepository.save(user)));
    }
@GetMapping("/{idUser}")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> getUserById(@PathVariable Long idUser) {
        User user= userRepository.findById(idUser).orElse(null);
        assert user != null;
        user.getRoles().size();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseObject("ok", "Get user successfully", userRepository.findById(idUser)));
    }
```

1. When I add data, I cannot see the role previously existing data.
2. I have attempted to access their roles, but only an empty array appears, and I have failed to create authority for them.
   [add role for user in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkTQy.png),
   [getUserById in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxTfS.png)

In version 2.7.2 everything work successfully. But I am currently stuck with this version 3.1.8.